# Footer cannot appear on CV using res.cls

Tags: resume, cv

I'm trying to add a footer into a CV using `res.cls`. I use some commands to define the footer but it still doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[line, margin]{res} 

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, linkcolor=ceruleanblue, urlcolor=ceruleanblue, anchorcolor=darkpowderblue, citecolor=darkpowderblue}

%%% Redefine font type and font color of section name
\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\scshape \textcolor{cobalt} }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}

\lfoot{\datestyle Firstname Lastname}
\cfoot{\datestyle Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}     % Use \thepage for counting page number
\rfoot{\datestyle Last updated: August 23, 2014}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a very old class and not included in texlive at all.

It does `\pagestyle{empty}` so there are no headers and footers. You can do

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

to use the fancyhdr settings, but then I had to define `\datestyle` which is used without being defined in your example

```
\documentclass[line, margin]{res} 

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, linkcolor=ceruleanblue, urlcolor=ceruleanblue, anchorcolor=darkpowderblue, citecolor=darkpowderblue}

%%% Redefine font type and font color of section name
\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\scshape \textcolor{cobalt} }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand\datestyle{???}

\fancyhf{}

\lfoot{\datestyle Firstname Lastname}
\cfoot{\datestyle Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}     % Use \thepage for counting page number
\rfoot{\datestyle Last updated: August 23, 2014}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse, @david-carlisle.

Sorry for the lack of definition of `datestyle`. Here is it: 

`\newcommand{\datestyle}{\color{datecolor} \footnotesize \rmfamily \upshape}`

I also added this command: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}` to avoid an unexpected bar in the header.

Now it works! But I have had a space before the `lfoot` of the footer (its width is equal to the width of the space where the section name locates. How to remove it? What I want is to display the footer in the whole line width of the page. Thanks!